# HTTP 404 Error when trying to run the servlet

Tags: servlets

### Im getting HTTP Status 404 - /Servlets_Tutorials/FirstServlet

FirstServlet.java

```
package com.servlet.learning;    
import java.io.*;    
import javax.servlet.*;
class FirstServlet implements Servlet {
ServletConfig config = null;

    public void init(ServletConfig config) {
        this.config = config;
        System.out.println("servlet is initialized");
    }


    public void service(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

        res.setContentType("text/html");

        PrintWriter out = res.getWriter();
        out.print("<html><body>");
        out.print("<b>hello simple servlet</b>");
        out.print("</body></html>");

    }


    public void destroy() {
        System.out.println("servlet is destroyed");
    }

    public ServletConfig getServletConfig() {
        return config;
    }

    public String getServletInfo() {
        return "copyright 2007-1010";
    }
    }
```

web.xml

```
<web-app>
<servlet>
<servlet-name>FirstServlet</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>FirstServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>FirstServlet</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/FirstServlet</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

1.What is the solution in order to resolve this error

2.All Environment variable are set (JAVA_HOME,PATH,CLASSPATH)

3.Need solution for executing the program is Eclipse IDE.

Comment: what is your web.xml config, please add it to your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make sure that your servlet class is not visible to

```
<servlet-class>FirstServlet</servlet-class>
```

you need to change

```
<servlet-class>com.servlet.learning.FirstServlet</servlet-class>
```